# Is there a way to create jenkins job on another server while creating it in the main server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a plugin to clone a job on to another server whilst creating a job on the main server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of the three ways explained [Copy Jobs from one Jenkins to another](https://staxmanade.com/2015/01/how-to-migrate-a-jenkins-job-to-new-jenkins-server/)

1. Copy the Jobs Directory
2. Use the Job Importer plugin (not advised if you have credentials in your job )
3. Using the CLI

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Import+Plugin

need to find a way to run it automatically after create every new job.

Comment: any possibility to trigger the creation of job?